# Use values of implicit array as variable in a macro

Tags: sas

I am looking to apply a macro to each value in an array. The code that doesn't work goes:

```
%let segments = SFAProx SFADist PAAK PABK TBT PTAP PTAM PTAD ATAP ATAM ATAD PAP PAM PAD DP OTHS;

%macro check_device(segment = );
    array devices &segment._PBA &segment._DES &segment._DCB &segment._BMS;
    if 2 in devices then &segment._device = 2;
    else &segment._device = 1;
    format &segment._device yn.;
%mend check_device;

data want;
    set have;

    array segment &segments;

    do over segment;
        %check_device(segment = segment)
    end;
run;
```

The macro `check_device` works when called as `%check_device(segment = SPAProx)`, but not when iterated over in a loop. How can I apply this macro to each value in the array?

EDIT:
I do not necessarily need to use a macro for this, if it can all be done within the data step that is fine. Effectively, over each 16 values for `segments` (I will use `SFAProx` as an example), I want to check whether there is a `2` in four columns (`SFAProx_PBA`, `SFAProx_DES`, `SFAProx_DCB`, `SFAProx_BMS`) and create a new variable `SFAProx_device` based on the result. This then needs to be repeated for each of the 16 values of `segments`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a macro?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to use a macro, but I couldn't make it work without a macro either!

Answer (score 1):

Change the macro to accept a LIST of values instead of just ONE VALUE.

There is no need to define an array for your problem.  Just use the WHICHN() function to check if 2 exists in any of a list of variables.

```
%macro check_device(segments = , suffix=PBA|DES|DCB|BMS);
  %local i segment j varlist;
  %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&segments,%str( )));
    %let segment=%scan(&segments,&i,%str( ));
    %let varlist=;
    %do j=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&suffix,|));
      %let varlist=&varlist &segment._%scan(&suffix,&j,|);
    %end;
&segment._device = 1 + (0<whichn(2,of &varlist));
format &segment._device yn.;
   %end;
%mend check_device;

%let segments = SFAProx SFADist PAAK PABK TBT PTAP PTAM PTAD ATAP ATAM ATAD PAP PAM PAD DP OTHS;
data want;
  set have;
  %check_device(segments = &segments)
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-macro way can use a hash to record the detection of a `2` value amongst a set of same prefix named variables.

Example:

A list of *_device variable names needs to be constructed.  I use `prxchange` to do that.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(2023);
  do row = 1 to 3;*100;
    array x 
      SFAProx_PBA SFADist_PBA PAAK_PBA PABK_PBA TBT_PBA PTAP_PBA PTAM_PBA PTAD_PBA ATAP_PBA ATAM_PBA ATAD_PBA PAP_PBA PAM_PBA PAD_PBA DP_PBA OTHS_PBA 
      SFAProx_DES SFADist_DES PAAK_DES PABK_DES TBT_DES PTAP_DES PTAM_DES PTAD_DES ATAP_DES ATAM_DES ATAD_DES PAP_DES PAM_DES PAD_DES DP_DES OTHS_DES 
      SFAProx_DCB SFADist_DCB PAAK_DCB PABK_DCB TBT_DCB PTAP_DCB PTAM_DCB PTAD_DCB ATAP_DCB ATAM_DCB ATAD_DCB PAP_DCB PAM_DCB PAD_DCB DP_DCB OTHS_DCB 
      SFAProx_BMS SFADist_BMS PAAK_BMS PABK_BMS TBT_BMS PTAP_BMS PTAM_BMS PTAD_BMS ATAP_BMS ATAM_BMS ATAD_BMS PAP_BMS PAM_BMS PAD_BMS DP_BMS OTHS_BMS 
      xx yy zz aa bb cc dd
    ;
    do over x;
      x = rand('integer',1,50);
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

%let segments = SFAProx SFADist PAAK PABK TBT PTAP PTAM PTAD ATAP ATAM ATAD PAP PAM PAD DP OTHS;

%let device_vars = %sysfunc(prxchange(s/ /_device /,-1,&segments%str( )));
%put &=device_vars;

data want;
  array devices &device_vars;

  set have;
  array vars _numeric_;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    length _segment $32;
    declare hash lookup();
    lookup.defineKey('_segment');
    lookup.defineDone();
  end;

  length name $33;
  do over vars;
    name = vname(vars);
    _segment = scan(name,1,'_');
    if missing(_segment) then continue;
    if findw("&segments",trim(_segment),' ','i') then 
      if scan(name,2,'_') in ('PBA', 'DES', 'DCB', 'BMS') then
        if countw(name,'_') = 2 then 
          if vars = 2 then lookup.replace();
  end;

  do over devices;
    _segment = scan(vname(devices),1,'_');

    devices = ifn (lookup.check() eq 0, 2, 1);
  end;

  lookup.clear();

  drop _: ;
run;
```